# MFC Application in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have developed a desktop application using MFC, which has FILE, EDIT, VIEW and HELP options,along with one pen to write on the opened document which saves as test1.  It is allowing me to open only test1 or test2 etc. Apart from these types of files, if i want to open PPTs or PDFs how can i do it?

The code to open a file is autogenerated by Visual Studio 2008. Now i need to modify the same.

Comment: "with one pen" ??? please explain, probable lost in translation.
Me think you need first need to improve your skill in MFC/C++; second is to check what is needed to open those file format, it might not be as simple as it looks (i've never had to think about it).

Good luck.
Max.

Answer (score 0):

This is something Microsoft doesn't provide any Wizards to do (at least not directly). The basic idea is that you have to create and add new document and view classes for the new file types. Then you need to add document strings to the string table to describe the association between the file extensions and the document/view classes. Then you register each document/view pair in the app class using the strings you added to the string table.

By far the easiest way to do this is to generate the document, view, and string in another (otherwise throwaway) application, grab the document, view, registration string and registration code from that application and put them into your application. Then generate another throwaway application for the next file extension.

That gives you a skeleton doc/view for each file extension. From there, it's up to you to write the code to actually open, display, edit, save, etc., that type of file. That's not going to be trivial for either PDF or (especially) PPT -- unless you "delegate" and use something like an ActiveX control to do the real work. If you want to do that, the Adobe ActiveX control works reasonably well (somewhat limited capabilities, but it'll show up essentially the same as a PDF in a web browser). Offhand I don't remember whether MS provides an ActiveX control for viewing PPT files. There is a free PPT viewer, but if memory serves it's an executable, rather than a control.